# QEMU outputs nothing when booting simple self-made OS kernel whose source code is from OSDev wiki

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system, gdb, kernel, qemu

I'm trying to booting the kernel whose code is osdev.org,But no matter how I tried,**I can't get the right output.**

I use QEMU to boot the kernel like this:

```bash
qemu-system-i386 -kernel myos.elf -serial stdio
```

And it didn't output **"Hello, kernel World!\n"** which the kernel supposed to output:

```bash
$ qemu-system-i386 -kernel myos.elf -serial stdio
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
```

As the shown above,**QEMU only output `VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900`**

And I tried to use gdb to debug the kernel,But **gdb told me that the remote has closed as soon as I connected gdb to the remote**:

```bash
# at the first terminal
$ qemu-system-i386 -s -S -kernel myos.elf -serial stdio
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900


# at the another terminal
$PREFIX/bin/i686-elf-gdb ./myos.elf 
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target=i686-elf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./myos.elf...
(gdb) target remote 127.0.0.1:5900
Remote debugging using 127.0.0.1:5900
Remote connection closed
(gdb)
```

And I tried to use the option `-d int` to see what happened:

```bash
$ qemu-system-i386 -d int -kernel myos.elf -serial stdio
VNC server running on 127.0.0.1:5900
SMM: enter
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=00014c00 ESP=00006c5c
EIP=000eae92 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00cf9300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f61e0 00000037
IDT=     000f621e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000080 CCD=00000001 CCO=LOGICB
EFER=0000000000000000
SMM: after RSM
EAX=00000001 EBX=00000000 ECX=02000000 EDX=02000628
ESI=0000000b EDI=02000000 EBP=00014c00 ESP=00006c5c
EIP=000eae92 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
CS =0008 00000000 ffffffff 00c09b00 DPL=0 CS32 [-RA]
SS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
DS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
FS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
GS =0010 00000000 ffffffff 00c09300 DPL=0 DS   [-WA]
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200 DPL=0 LDT
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00 DPL=0 TSS32-busy
GDT=     000f61e0 00000037
IDT=     000f621e 00000000
CR0=00000011 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=EFLAGS
EFER=0000000000000000
Servicing hardware INT=0x08
...
```

I showed these message to chatgpt, and she told me **`Servicing hardware INT=0x08` means the kernel worked well which means it counldn't output nothing...**

I'm **using Ubuntu22.04 on VMware**,and I **complied the needed tools** on my own(binutils,gdb,gcc,qemu,grub)

My code is the same as the one https://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones given.And I tried code from https://wiki.osdev.org/User:Zesterer/Bare_Bones, but it failed too.

I will be very grateful if you can find out what's wrong and I'll be very happy if you could give a simple explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Port 5900 is the VNC server, which is for the graphical display, not gdb. QEMU's gdb stub listens for connections on port 1234 by default, so tell gdb to connect to that port. See the documentation: https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/gdb.html

Comment: Oh,thank you, I will try it.And do you have any idea about why the qemu didn't output well?Is the code wrong?

Comment: "No output" is what you should expect if your guest crashes before it gets to the point where it sends anything to the screen...

Comment: I tried to use gdb like what you said, but gdb shows "Cannot find bounds of current function" when I tried to use command "n".And when I use command "backtrace", it shows only "#0  0x0000fff0 in ?? ()".Is this my gcc's fault or QEMU's fault?